# Github: Unable to push to remote branch due to work on remote not found locally; --force did not work either

Tags: git, github

I am taking an online course at Harvard where I am supposed to submit the project to a branch of their private repository when completed.  In my ignorance somehow the remote branch I created got populated with work from a previously submitted project. The problem is that we don't have any flexibility in the naming of the branch.  I tried to just delete the branch, but it is marked as "default" and I could not figure out how to lift the `default` designation to allow the deletion of the branch.  So instead, I deleted the contents of the said remote branch, then tried pushing my completed project to the said remote.

```
    git remote add origin https://github.com/me50/<username>.git

   
    git push --set-upstream origin web50/projects/2020/x/wiki
```

After entering the `username` and `password`, I get the following error.

```
    Error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/me50/<username>.git
    hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
    hint: not have locally.  This is usually caused by another repository pushing
    hint: to the same ref.  You may want to first integrate the remote changes
    hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
    hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Then I tried to force the push:

```
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/web50/projects/2020/x/wiki
remote: error: Cannot force-push to this protected branch
```

This is my own assignment and project; not collaborating with anyone else. I am hesitant to perform a `pull` request since I really don't know what will happen to my local repository.  The remote is empty other than records of the files deleted.  I suppose I have to do a "merge" after the pull, but not being fluent in git, I am afraid of doing something wrong in the syntax and even going deeper into this time sinkhole.  Thıs should be a simple drag and drop operation but it has evolved into 2 hours of effort with no results.  I tried `Github desktop` and that is what I used to delete the files on the remote branch, but no joy on a simple drag and drop.

Please help.  Thank you.

UPDATE 9-16-2020:

The branch I had created is off of a private repository that belongs to Harvard.  So I am unable to delete it or force a push to it.  I could not figure out how to get it out of `default` status if this is possible for a protected branch.  So I am stuck in a dilemma where I can create but not delete.

From the advice of @Matt D, I am contemplating a `gıt merge` with the `--ours` option.  I have learned that the `git pull` command is actually a combination of the `git fetch` and `git merge` commands. So, instead of a `git pull` I would do a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge` with the `--ours` option.  If anyone can help me on verifying this, and what the exact syntax of the `gıt fetch` and the subsequent `git merge` should look like, I would really appreciate it.  The devil is in the details.

Update 9-16-2020

The fetch followed by the merge then the push resulted in the following error:

```
Error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/me50/<username>.git
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart.  Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

Then I tried a pull

```
git pull -s ours https://github.com/me50/<username>.git
```

and I got the following:

```
* branch       HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Comment: What was the result of using `git push --force` (assuming that your local copy represents the way you want things to look)?

Comment: @larsks "remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/web50/projects/2020/x/wiki" new line "remote: error: Cannot force-push to this protected branch" .  Yes, the local copy is exactly what is desired on the remote branch.

Comment: Do you control the remote repository? If you do, the solution is to visit `https://github.com/YOURUSERNAME/YOURREPONAME/settings/branches` and delete the branch protection rules. Or more accurately, this is **a** solution, and not necessarily the best one, but I don't know enough about your use case.

Comment: @larsks the branch is protected so I could not delete the branch protection rules.  The git pull command is actually a combination of the "git fetch" and "git merge" commands and I need to use the "--ours" option on the "git merge" command in order for the local branch to override the remote for the merge conflicts.  I just need help on the exact syntax on these commands, if you can provide these in an answer.  I reviewed and upvoted your questions and some of the many answers in your profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to do a pull and resolve any merge conflicts. Keep in mind here that you are always able to revert back to a specific commit or abort the merge during the conflict resolution stage. One thing that could help with resolving merge conflicts is by using `--ours` or `--theirs`: [Link](https://nitaym.github.io/ourstheirs/)

Essentially by using `--ours` you can force it to keep the local version of your files, which then you could push to the remote once you've resolved those conflicts

EDIT: Here is the flow that you should follow to achieve your goal

1. To undo any changes that may have occurred while you were debugging and trying various things, run `git reset --hard` to remove any uncommitted changes from your working directory.
2. run `git pull` which will fetch from the remote and initiate the merge process
3. At this point I'm assuming there will be merge conflicts. Run `git status` to see which files require conflict resolution. For the sake of example lets assume that `file1.java` is a file with merge conflicts
4. For your case since you don't care what is in the remote branch, we will use the `--ours` option to resolve the conflicts. Remember that using `--ours` is telling git "No, we don't care about what was in the remote. Resolve conflicts for this file always using the code from *our local version*"

To do this for `file1.java`, run `git checkout --ours file1.java`. You should do the same thing for any files it lists as conflicted file.

5. Test your project. Please make sure your project still works as expected at this point. This is incredibly important as you do not want to keep any breaking changes. If you notice it is not working correctly, either fix it manually or abort the merge and restart the process.
6. Commit the resolved files. This will be just like a normal commit, like `git commit -am "Resolved merge conflicts"`
7. Push your changes and hope the remote accepts them. Then you're done!

Comment: Thank you for that.  Please see update to the question. The git pull command is actually a combination of the "git fetch" and "git merge" commands and I need to use the "--ours" option on the "git merge" command in order for the local branch to override the remote for the merge conflicts. I just need help on the exact syntax on these commands, if you can provide these in your answer. I reviewed and upvoted your other answers in your profile.

Comment: Hi Ed, I have added a more detailed explanation of how I think you would achieve this. Keep in mind that I'm not 100% sure that this won't break anything for you, but I'm not sure if you have any other options (that I'm aware of). If this merge ends up breaking your project, I think you will need to fix it manually. One other way you could try to fix it is to save the version of the project you want somewhere else (`directory A`), then pull the remote into a new directory `directory B`, then copy `directory A` to `directory B` and commit and push like normal